# add currency symbol to result of SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is the issue I want to transform the balance (l.slsprice) into dollar signs $. How do I so?

```
select
s.ordnbr,
s.ordnbr+l.lineref as copy,
(l.slsprice*(s.qtyord-s.qtycloseship)) as balance
from CAL.DBO.opssosched s (nolock)
join CAL.DBO.opssoline l (nolock) on s.ordnbr=l.ordnbr
```

The result I am looking for should be:

```
Balance
$6.77
$5
$42
```

Comment: This is almost always best handled at the presentation layer

Answer (score 2):

use format for sql-server 2012+

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql

```
format (<field>,'C')

Select format(23.00,'$#,##0.##')   -- no cents as per comment
```

Comment: This includes the cents in all cases -- which doesn't bother me.

Comment: Plus 1 --  Select format(23.00,'$#,##0.##')   would remove cents if needed